# Swift connect to network smb drive

Tags: xcode, swift

I've been trying to find a way to connect to my network drive via swift 2 and Xcode 7. I can connect to my desktop or documents directory but not to my server. I have played around with NSString/NSURL etc but to no avail. Below is my code for reference:

```
//Target file
let myFile = "myTextFile.txt"

// Write this text.
let myText = "Dante, The Divine Comedy"

//Target path
if let myDir : NSString = ("smb://path/to/text/file/on/network/server/myTextFile.txt") {
let myPath = myDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(myFile);

// Writting
do {
try myText.writeToFile(myPath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch let error as NSError {
print("Failed writing to URL: \(myPath), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

//Reading
do {
let myText = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: myPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch let error as NSError {
print("Failed writing to URL: \(myPath), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
} //closes if
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any luck in getting files from smb?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are appending the file name to the path which already includes the file name ("smb://path/to/text/file/on/network/server/myTextFile.txt" + "myTextFile.txt" = "smb://path/to/text/file/on/network/server/myTextFile.txtmyTextFile.txt")